# Distribution of the change in Hamming distance between two sequences

Tags: pr.probability, coding-theory, hamming-distance, bioinformatics

Suppose I have two strings $s_1$ and $s_2$ of equal length $L$ with an alphabet size of $k \geq 2$. Suppose further that these two strings initially have a Hamming distance equal to $d_0 = H(s_1,s_2)$.

I then proceed through each character in one of the strings (say $s_2$), changing with probability $\mu$ the character to another distinct value in the alphabet, uniformly from the $k-1$ choices remaining. The number of edits is therefore distributed $\text{Binomial}(\mu,L)$.

Denote the new string $s^{'}_2$. Can I say anything about the distribution of $d_0 - H(s_1,s^{'}_2)$?

I can see that the likelihood of a positive change versus a negative change must be dependent on $d_0$, as clearly edits to two strings with a large number of matches is more likely to induce an increase in Hamming distance rather than a decrease.

I can also see that it might not be possible to give a complete answer for the case where the alphabet size $k>2$, since a flip of an unmatched character may or may not result in a match given we don't know the exact contents of the string $s_1$ it is being compared to. In this instance, we can assume that the string $s_1$ and $s_2$ were initially sampled uniformly from the space of possible strings, which I think should make it tractable.

Comment: "to a another distinct character in the alphabet". -- I think the choice of that other character should be specified. Is it according to a specific conditional distribution?

Comment: Sorry - hopefully my edit clarifies

Answer (score 0):

An edit on a character that matched will no longer match ; an edit on a character that did not match will match with probability $\frac1{k-1}$. Define $X_1, \dots, X_{d_0}$ be Bernoulli variables with parameter $\mu$, and $Y_{d_0+1},\dots,Y_L$ be Bernoulli with parameter $\frac\mu{k-1}$, all independent. Then $H(s_1,s_2')$ has the same law as $d_0+\sum X_i-\sum Y_j$, i.e. $d_0- H(s_1,s_2')$ has the same law as $-\sum X_i+\sum Y_j$.

Comment: I think that there is an inversion between $d_0$ and $n-d_0$. There are $n-d_0$ position where the two strings initially match, so the variation of the distance is given by $n_0-d$ Bernoulli r.v. with parameter $\mu$ and $d_0$ Bernoulli r.v. with parameter $\mu/(k-1)$. Say also that the Bernoulli r.v. are independent.